# CahartcreS awppnig (Character Swapping)

Tags: code-golf, string

### Intro/Background

I was looking at "You Had One Job" pictures lately, and noticed an old favourite of mine:

[image: SHCOOL]

And I said to myself: "I need a program that can generate text like that".
So I devised a set of rules for character swapping and wrote a CGCC challenge!

### The Challenge

Given a single string as input, output a string with its inner characters swapped. This can be done by:

- Leaving the first letter as is
- Swapping each pair of characters thereafter
- Leaving the last letter as is. If the string is of an odd length (i.e. the length of the string mod 2 is 1), leave the last two letters as they are.

### Example Inputs/Outputs

```
School -> Shcool
Somebody -> Smobedoy
Character -> Cahartcer
CGCC -> CCGC
Stack Exchange! -> SatkcE cxahgne!
Never gonna give you up -> Nvereg noang vi eoy uup
```

Walkthrough on swapping

```
School (Length: 6)
S
 hc
   oo
     l
Shcool


Somebody (Length: 8)
S
 mo
   be
     do
       y
Smobedoy


Character (Length: 9)
C
 ah
   ar
     tc
       er
Cahartcer

Stack Exchange! (Length: 15)
S
 at
   kc
     E 
       cx
         ah
           gn
             e!
SatkcE cxahgne!
```

### Rules

- Input/output can be taken/given in any convenient format
- The input will not contain newlines
- Minimum input length is 4
- Input will only contain printable ASCII characters

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the lowest bytes wins.

*Sorry about the last test case everyone. It's fixed now*

Comment: Are we allowed to modify the input and make it the output?

Comment: @JL2210 As stated in the challenge, input and output can be taken and given in any convient format. So if modifying the input and making it the output makes this challenge easier, then go ahead and do so!

Comment: Bonus challenge: make a program that still works when ran through the swapping process.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the convention in Python, strings are immutable, while lists are not. Can I take a list and output a list instead of string?

Comment: @justhalf As stated in the challenge, input and output can be taken and given in any convenient format. So if taking and outputting a list is easier for you, feel free to do so.

Comment: Why no explaining the rickroll testcase?

Comment: @Joao-3 because it'd be too long an explanation to be useful.

Answer (score 31):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 31 bytes

```hs
f(a:b:c:d:e)=a:c:f(b:d:e)
f x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy7DgIhEEX7/YqRWKyJX0BCZSyttjTGDOwgZHkFKNCfR1y7c@5JrsGykXO96xm55IqvnE4CB@hZ7jJpaKL1SqUWcWeLMjE6dmZL9CTj@h54MZhRVcq/uaLa4NqUwfCiA3tMHm0QHtPtCSnbUOEIH5tgPxw8Cui/9S8)

Avoids having to special-case omitting the first character by having extracting it be part of the recursive definition.

Answer (score 29):

### brainfuck, 28 bytes

```
,.,[>,>,[<.[-]<.>>>]<<[.>]>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fR08n2k7HTifaRi9aN9ZGz87OLtbGJlrPLtYu9v//4JLE5GwF14rkjMS89FRFAA)

First, we print the first character. Then we read the second character and enter the main loop. (`,.,[`)

When entering the main loop, we expect the first character of a pair to be in the current cell, and we read the next two into the next two cells (`>,>,`). The tape then looks like this:

```
[pair1] [pair2] [nextpair1] [0]
                     ^
```

Then, if `nextpair1` exists, we know there's going to be at least one character after the current pair, so we can output the two characters in this current pair in reverse (`[<.[-]<.>>>]`) – the triple `>` at the end moves us to the location after `nextpair1` to break out of the loop. Otherwise, we're at the end of the string, so we go back to `pair1` (`<<`) and print as many characters as we received in order (`[.>]`).

The main loop will end here if this was the end of the string (`>]`). If not, recall that we ended at the `[0]` in the diagram above after the check to see if `nextpair1` existed. So the `<<[.>]` would have brought the pointer to `pair2` (which was cleared) instead of `pair1`, and then `>]` restarts the main loop, but with the cursor pointing at `nextpair1`, which is exactly what we want.

Comment: Wow. That's really impressive.

Answer (score 10):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 12 bytes

```
V`^.|..(?=.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8D8sIU6vRk9Pw95WT/P//@DkjPz8HK7g/NzUpPyUSi7njMSixOSS1CKugABnd67gksTkbAXXiuSMxLz0VEUuv9Sy1CKF9Py8vESF9MyyVIXK/FKF0gIA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: `V` reverses each match. The first character is matched separately, then characters are matched in pairs as long as there is still one character left that is unreversed.

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
Ḣ,Ṫjṭ2/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AXUAiv9qZWxsef//4biiLOG5qmrhua0yL/874oCcIC0@IOKAnTvDhwrhu7TDh@KCrFn//3NjaG9vbApzb21lYm9keQpjaGFyYWN0ZXIKQ0dDQwpTdGFjayBFeGNoYW5nZSEKTmV2ZXIgZ29ubmEgZ2l2ZSB5b3UgdXA)

A full program taking a string as its argument and printing the swapped string. Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving a byte!

### Explanation

```
Ḣ       | Head
 ,Ṫ     | Paired with tail
   j    | Join with:
    ṭ2/ | The remainder, pair wise reduced by tacking the left item in the pair to the end of the right
```

Comment: Damn this is awesome

Comment: `Ḣ,Ṫjṭ2/` saves a byte. (I like the nine: `J’!Œœ§Ṃœ?`)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s[3:]and s[:3:2]+f(s[1:5:2]+s[4:])or s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcixDoIwEIDh3ae4dILoIuhyiZNxdWFsGI7SUiL0mrYQePoKy58vv9@TZVflbF4TzV1PEDHKGltyPUSJNVbt1RRR3vF5MsoHtiUHiNkc3WB0IBplmSdxEw3PuuN@P/i2FEglHc6dSP3gsylLbtDH@OpVBxjYOYJhXDXsvMDiBV7Ah9GlwhRbWeY/)

Based off my [Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197489/20260). I tried a more direct port using splatted input, but it was clunky:

**57 bytes**

```python
f=lambda a,b,c,*d:d[1:]and a+c+f(b,*d)or a+b+c+''.join(d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fci9DoIwFEDh3ae46UILjYmOJE7G1YXRONz@0Sr0kqYQePpat3O@5cie4rUUd5twVgYBpZJatqY3r0v/xmgAO905rqoJSvVU/aY5fyhEbkRxFXcIEdigPdHEJBtotorMUfPuMaHONv05o/7CY9ce42grPO1mE4wUI8IYNgsHrbAurD/BkkLM3PF2F6L8AA)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Do you need the `f=` part?
In [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197485/16337) it doesn't include the `f=` part.

Comment: @justhalf I do because I have a recursive call to `f`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Anyway, nice trick with the recursion! I can only match your second version with [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197569/16337) due to the return and the function definition.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>27</s> 20 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Requires `⎕IO←0`.

```apl
⊢⊇⍨∘⍋≢⌊1+⍳∘≢+2×2|⍳∘≢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/x91LXrU1f6od8WjjhmPersfdS561NNlqP2odzNIoHORttHh6UY1cO7/NKCuR719EAO6mg@tN37UNhHICw5yBpIhHp7B/9MU1IOTM/Lzc9S5QMz83NSk/JRKMMc5I7EoMbkktQjCc3d2hqgpSUzOVnCtSM5IzEtPVQSL@aWWpRYppOfn5SUqpGeWpSpU5pcqlBaoAwA)

Explanation and walk-through for `"Somebody"` and `"Character"`:

`⍳∘≢` the indices of the length; `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

`2|` two-mod of that; `[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]`, `[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]`

`2×` twice that; `[0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2]`, `[0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0]`

`⍳∘≢+` add the indices of the length to that; `[0,3,2,5,4,7,6,9]`, `[0,3,2,5,4,7,6,9,8]`

`1+` increment that; `[1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10]`, `[1,4,3,6,5,8,7,10,9]`

`≢⌊` the minimum of the length and that; `[1,4,3,6,5,8,7,8]`, `[1,4,3,6,5,8,7,9,9]`

`⍋` the grade (the indices that would sort it) of that; `[0,2,1,4,3,6,5,7]`, `[0,2,1,4,3,6,5,7,8]`

`⊢⊇⍨∘` use that to reorder the string; `"Smobedoy"`, `"Cahartcer"`

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg) `-p`, 26 bytes

```perl6
s:g[^.||)>..$||..]=$/.flip
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7/YKj06Tq@mRtNOT0@lpkZPL9ZWRV8vLSez4P//4OSM/PwcruD83NSk/JRKLueMxKLE5JLUIq7gksTkbAXXiuSMxLz0VMV/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Comment: Seems to fail for odd number of chars. For instance `heidi` and `heidila`.

Comment: @KjetilS. Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
f=->s{s[/(.)(.)(.)(.+)/]?$1+$3+f[$2+$4]:s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1664ujhaX0NPE4a0NfVj7VUMtVWMtdOiVYy0VUxirYpr/0crBSdn5OfnKOkoBefnpiblp1QCmc4ZiUWJySWpRSDhksTkbAXXiuSMxLz0VKCAX2pZapFCen5eXqJCemZZqkJlfqlCaYFSrF5uYkF1TUVNgUJadEVs7X8A)

Comment: [If you want, cribbing the Retina solution directly saves 5 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcvRCoIwFIDhVxkjQqGOT2BdRLfdeGkG2zpuUTrZnGy4PfvSu58PfuN4yH39zOeLXS1I63hRvSACFNcayqpcD0cwuKCxmFJuaSOU1j96oo0ekOt32PKmmGFiRrPzzMSX3L1QbJS4wWOfidTjyIj8LEiCdsRNtIOBTWv0cSJ967uU/w "Ruby – Try It Online") or you could enable `-p` mode to drop it all the way down to 30 bytes.

Comment: This would be unfair, it's a completely different idea.

Comment: Understandable. It seems histocrat has taken that approach for their Ruby solution, and even shorter than my suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), <s>48</s> 40 bytes

```
({}<{({}<({}<>)>)<>}<>{{({}<>)<>}{}}<>>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v9fo7rWphpEgLCdpp2mjR2Qrq6GcIGc6logw07z////SiGpxSUKwSVFmXnpikr/dR0B)

This doesn't work for strings that contain null bytes (unless the null byte is the first byte of the string).

### Explanation

```
({}<...>) Store the first element for later
  {({}<({}<>)>)<>}... Move the stack over in twos (preserving the order of each pair moved)
    <>{...{}}<>
      {({}<>)<>} Move everything back in ones
```

The one complex part is the `<>{...{}}<>`.  Since moving over in twos can pick up an extra zero from the bottom of the stack we need to removing when bringing things back.  Conveniently our main loop will stop when it hits a zero, so when it hits a zero we destroy that zero and, if the next thing is not zero we try again.

This means we will only stop if there are two zeros in a row, which since the input cannot contain zeros, will only occur at the bottom of the stack.  In the process we will get rid of any zeros that are present, which fixes our extra zero issue.

## Works for all inputs, <s>114</s> 112 bytes

```
({}<([](())){({}[()]<(()[{}])>)}({}{}<([]){{}({}<({}<>)>)<>([])}>{}<>){(<{}({}<{}>)>)}{}([]){{}({}<>)<>([])}<>>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYsxCoBADAS/olZJ4Q9CwDdod1xxiqgIFmoX8vaY80Astpid3fFM27GmaTcDUYIQARBRHAJgJKcgGpFRvSoLFNF37GE3xLlUflGAihXNzi@/x7clZjSzZpivu@rvczuWurG2ewA)

Nearly all of the code is devoted to making this work for even length inputs.

Answer (score 4):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>117</s> ... <s>82</s></sup> 80 bytes

```cpp
#import<map>
#define f(s)for(int i=1;i<s.size()-2;)s[i++]^=s[i++]^=s[i+1]^=s[i];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/LbsIwELznK7ZGQnYpqPSYOPRQ9doLx5ZKxtkEq8S2/KCliG@njqMifPCuxzOzs9LaudwL3V0uE9Vb4wLvhV0VkwZbpRFa6llrHFU6gKqXleJ@4dUvUjZ/qph/V7PZ5rO@rcuxbqpkqOU@Ngj8gDIYl1yviDI@OBT9qhice6E0ZXAqIB0fmrIcFTz3ial0t4KAPnio4UTWcmfMnjyQtelxa5pjal92wgkZ0A1wEPILXn/kLm2GCXjDAzrojNYCOnVAOJoI0d7KYP0trE2DyLnKOdLaQEUMZponQzkG@I@ZKXSA2PWd40oTA3AOdJpldzVM77NyscUu7/kM5EOTZEgIG5jD7zjznG@HIToNj1VxvvwB)

Saved 11 bytes thanks to @AZTECCO!!!
Saved 2 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat!!!

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 40 bytes

```hs
f(a:b:c:d)=b:a:f(c:d)
f x=x
g(a:b)=a:f b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy7CgIxFET7fMU1WOyCXxBIJZZW2onITTYvNi@yKVZ/PiZazZkzMBa3VXnfmp6QCSbZMnPBkOlpINGw852Ysc28WxCtqq1u/EHvI@mJ3qRNyQ9IQYm0vDueLRaUVZWhK8oVLru0GI060CcJ6CIPmK8vyMXFCkf4uAy/4859AfNv7Qs)

xnor has [a shorter version of this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197489/56656) that combines `f` and `g` into a single function.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 62 bytes

```python
lambda x:x[0]+re.sub("(.)(.)",r"\2\1",x[1:-1])+x[-1]
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYixCoMwFAB3v@KRKUErtd2ETqVrF0d1iDEaqeaF1yjx69MUDu44d3qD9h6nRxdXuQ2jhFCH9trnpMvvPnDGS5FgBbHu1lWsCG1VX6pe5KFNypbNIXkgHSckCLBYYI0yiCsrWIObHnA8Uz6NJKm8pv/2Un3gFZSRdtZpvPWhCWa0VsK8HBpO3GF3rM7A0WI9n3gQIv4A)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
¦¨2ô€RJ¹θ¹н.ÁJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9vc2FiaWX//8Kmwqgyw7TigqxSSsK5zrjCudC9LsOBSv//U3RhY2sgRXhjaGFuZ2Uh)

```
¦¨2ô€RJ¹θ¹н.ÁJ
¦¨             # Delete the first and last letter
  2ô           # Break into groups of 2
    €R         # Reverse each of them
      J        # Join it back together
       ¹θ¹н    # Push the last and first letter of the input
           .Á  # Rotate stack, so the first letter is first
             J # Join the items in the stack
```

Comment: `€R` can be `í`. Also, by using the `ć` builtin with a `s`wap, you won't need the `¹н.Á` portion: [`ćs¨2ôíJ¹θJ` (10 bytes)](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX//8SHc8KoMsO0w61KwrnOuEr//1N0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlIQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
h1Ué ¤ò mÔq
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=aDFV6SCk8iBt1HE&input=IkNoYXJhY3RlciBTd2FwcGluZyI)

```
h1Ué ¤ò mÔq     :Implicit input of string U
h1              :Overwrite from the 1st (0-indexed) character on with
  Ué            :  Rotate U to the right
     ¤          :  Slice off the first 2 characters
      ò         :  Split into pairs
        m       :  Map
         Ô      :    Reverse
          q     :  Join
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) -pl, 27 bytes

```ruby
gsub /^.|..(?=.)/,&:reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCgIxDADQvV@RSRS0twviIK4u3YW0hvbwbEraHhb8diO@/Un3QzXW7mG624@12/PJ7qb95ii0klRSdSExL8bxizw/hrkkFAyNxLiG4QnXd0iYI5nbf0DknBHivBIM7tCL@XJpM@eqh7L8AA)

**Alternate solution with the same bytecount, but a regex nobody else has used yet:**

```ruby
gsub /(^|.)(.(?=.))/,'\2\1'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxDsIgEADQ/b7itkKiNLobB@PahbUxAbxAY@UIhUYSv118L1fbevdbtTiKx1dJocT1oqQcD8N8nk9D79oF5hU0v8nys8EtmGxcoQy6GPfC@8cFEz3BRDtl9ByjQb/shI0r1gQ/TmXhuPVjWv8)

Comment: `-l` mode is not needed at all; the program works just fine with just `-p`.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s><sup>24</sup></s> 19 bytes

```
C.~[:}:_2<@|.\#\@}.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/nfXqoq1qreKNbBxq9GKUYxxq9f5rcqUmZ@QrpCmoJyYlp6ij8FLRuGlIfGQpFGXqXP8B)

Creates the boxed indexes representing the cyclic form of the permutation we need (bookeeping), and then applies it `C.` to the input.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 40 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>s[3]?s[0]+s[2]+f(s[1]+s.slice(3)):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYvLDoIwEADvfgVyakMkKjcNejB@AceGw7qUtli7hG18fH3VqyHeJpmZAe7AOLkxrgJ1OqW@5vrAqmqPrNZtwWrbFr1gtflwyd6hFpWUO05Igcnr0pMRvcgZLZHPpdwvfkxDN32h7jXnThYmwKin2TECXrPzEy0Eo5d//6x5wDi6YL5VegM)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>41</s> 40 bytes

-1 bytes thanks to Arnauld

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/(?!^)(.)(.)(?=.)/g,"$2$1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYvLCsIwEADvfkUbekhAU/QqtQfxC3oX1u02qY3ZkBQfXx/RoxRhbjNzhTskjGOYN557ykOTU3NIOlJwgCRr2ZZnJfWXttGqNmtR7aqtUBnZJ3akHRs5SJHQMjuh1H71Yzq@0YX715I7WoiAM8XFcQacitMTLXhD5d@/6B4QwujNp8pv)

Comment: You can use `(?!^)` instead of `(?<=.)`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43232659/2004841) on SO.

Comment: Actually I think @histocrat's regex might be even shorter still.

Answer (score 2):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 15 characters

```
\A?=?
??\P?=$2?
```

The only interesting point here is the use of

> `\P`       Position -- leave input stream here after the template matches

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ echo -n 'School' | gema '\A?=?;??\P?=$2?'
Shcool
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/P8bR3taey94@JsDeVsXI/v//4OSM/PwcAA) | [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lVDBbsIwDD2TrzBVR@CAkJB2mqoOVWjahU3jCNUUUtNWQFKlKaJi@/bOSSW2w3bYxXnxe7afvRN10WUoj8IgTBdgsbbvUtQYjdlgw9ey0PrI04ivC@mQT@oT7nTW@vRJ7zDTrSeSQhghLRrHJIJ@VtLHU09J4rME@iZWyAMsL7IQKseh7yXsQS5BXkSRK0o52QrPaCDXSgnIyzNCqxtoKidfEYM5KE0N4FwC6hYaotiEscqUyu6Bf8DddH5fwy/vnOJWceDPqmosvW9YN0cHlpcKaYuM4MuBM7bXBkonoghBeB3ejrR5TD@DB8g0GxhfHQXhGJCOBlMn9VUBTZvpys5yPIlZbaQHwLvtIo5iFsfb1zgK53HHYRIwNviH99uEIOznO3T9ttfT5BGcr83mhy6K/pKmKYxG/RJuf2cq0wq7Lw)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>51</s> 48 bytes

```c
f(char*s,z){*++s^=*s^=s[1]^=*++s;z>5&&f(s,z-2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddDPa8IwFAfwe/6KNw/S1AhLk46N4C4ydhvCjuIgy9Japon0h0zFv71LbGNlsEPg5Us@7yVRU7WRJm/bLFJrWcYVOeJTPJlUH7PYrWpJV65ye3F8TsfjLHIHpgkW57YwNWxlYSDCJwQeg1yuZqN3tbZ2MxIIdk1dRRK7KoskecDCB9AlQdALsVv9ab8OA6K9ouTxynwWWOLZ3JVS1boMzh1KepiQpw52UXDMu8Vi/jqMYr1ghAfBbgS/XLCW6hteflxkcn03YN5jTmgaNL/Rqddveq9LyK0xEvJir@FgG2h2Q5e075KShIUuPkOlrpvSwL1A57b7VxT@Cl1fj/x70J8ron@G/gI)

A recursive solution that modifies the original string

Saved 3 thanks to @ceilingcat suggestion to use `^=`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 57 bytes

```python
def f(s):s[1:-2:2],s[2:-1:2]=s[2:-1:2],s[1:-2:2];return s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcmxDoMgFEDRvV/xwiI0OGg3mk5N1y6OpgPFh5BaIIBGv57axe3k3rBl492llAE1aJqYSH0j6la0L576VtTNrtshftxrxDxHB6loH2EF64B0yng/EU46/8W3H7addyOjVBnjP2epPvBYlZFuxD08ccEIo3dOwmgXhM3PMAciThCidZmeNZ1synRljCcMt6pi5Qc)

Accepts a list and returns a list.

The idea is to simply take the alternating slices and swap them.

Do let me know if the boilerplate stuff can be shortened in Python submissions.

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 machine code, 13 bytes

Unassembled listing:

```
 46         INC  SI         ; skip first char 
 8B FE      MOV  DI, SI     ; point DI to string 
 D1 E9      SHR  CX, 1      ; divide counter by 2 with round down 
 49         DEC  CX         ; skip last char 
        CLOOP: 
 AD         LODSW           ; load next two chars 
 86 E0      XCHG AH, AL     ; reverse chars 
 AB         STOSW           ; store next two chars 
 E2 FA      LOOP CLOOP      ; keep looping
 C3         RET             ; return to caller
```

Input/output string in `[SI]`, length in `CX`.

**PC-DOS test program output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 17 bytes

```
rt2cog_j)<-++.+RT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/qMQoOT89PkvTRldbW087KOT/f@eMxKLE5JLUIgA)

```
rt  # Rotate the string left
2co # Split into chunks of 2
g_j # Take pair of first and last out
)<- # Reverse each chunk
++.+# Join everything back together
RT  # Rotate the string right
```

For even length input only you can shave a single character:

```
RT2col_)<-++.+RT
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 125 bytes

```
character(99)a,b(99)
read('(a)'),a
j=len_trim(a)
b=[a(1:1),(a(i+1:i+1),a(i:i),i=2,j-1,2),a(j:j)]
print*,(b(i)(1:1),i=1,j)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCoMwEEX3OUV2nWnHRdwZ8Aq9QCll1GgntFGGKPT0qeLi8z6P/8dZs3KqpvEspfRvVu5zUGgaZOoOGA08wAUYL0hsYvsJ6ZVVvrsxXftgcN4hAYPcnN@zr0C8IElbU6wc1YeJPuLTLCopXwk6EDx/0jqKaEIaSrmHLaid5pTYTrIF@5tXuy5/)

Shame string manipulation in Fortran is so wordy as every substring needs two references. The main magic is mapping a to a character array via:

```
[a(1:1),            ! Prepend first char
(a(i+1:i+1),a(i:i), ! Swap a(i+1) for a(i)
  i=2,j-1,2)        ! For i in 2..n-1
,a(j:j)]            ! Append last char
```

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 48 bytes

Man, I love J

```
(1{.]),([:,[:(|."1)_2[\1}.]}.~_1-2|#),]{.~_1-2|#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WSsOwWi9WU0cj2kon2kqjRk/JUDPeKDrGsFYvtlavLt5Q16hGWVMnthrG/p@anJGvkKag7pdallqkkJ6fl5eokJ5ZlqpQmV@qUFqg/h8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>74</s> 71 bytes

Found a more idiomatic `Zsh` solution. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBC4IwGIDh@37F0h0UCpnHQiIk6NLJbrLDnN9cpE50MEv87WtG8B6ew/uZlJvA6MFgmA30NdRNqysko3hxNiP0NIzP3khMbEkZWWyZ7kloD5QlSRR2cXTeSsj98shvZcr@oGz17/F3rg6E0itCEhceut2gO6h0/fbMFR@5MDB6B4Xh4oWvs1C8b2AXIPcF)

```sh
w=$1;printf $w[1]${w[2,$#w-1]//(#m)(?)(?)/$MATCH[2]$MATCH[1]}${w:$#w-1}
```

<sub>[74 bytes:](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9v9xWxdC6oCgzryRNQaU82jDWOi2/SCFTQaPaSE9PJVpFuVzXKFZPz6hWE6EoU9swFkTFWtvY2KhUl1upAEVq/9dycaUpBCdn5OfngBj5ualJ@SmVQKZzRmJRYnJJahGQrRRckpicreBakZyRmJeeqqjE9R8A)
`w=$1;printf $w[1];for i ({2..$[$#w-2]..2})printf $w[i+1]$w[i];<<<${w:$i+1}`</sub>

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 104 bytes

```
 P =LEN(1)
 INPUT P . F REM . S
S S P . X P . Y REM . S
 F =F Y X
 GT(SIZE(S),2) :S(S)
O OUTPUT =F S
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/XyFAwdbH1U/DUJNLwdMvIDQEKKCn4KYQ5OoLpIO5ghWCwSIRYDISLg5UYusG5EdwKbiHaAR7RrlqBGvqGGkqWAUDGVz@Cv6hISDTgIqCuVz9XP7/d85ILEpMLkktAgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
§θ⁰Ｆ⪪✂θ¹±¹¦¦¦²⮌ι§θ±¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMOxxDMvJbVCo1BHwUBT05orLb9IQSO4ICezRCM4JzM5FSRhqKPgl5qeWJKqYaipqaNgpKmpANEclFqWWlScqpEJ0olhHkKPpvX//8ElicnZCq4VyRmJeempilz/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Works with strings of at least 2 characters. Explanation:

```
§θ⁰
```

Print the first character of the string.

```
Ｆ⪪✂θ¹±¹¦¦¦²
```

Split the inner slice of the string into 2-character substrings.

```
⮌ι
```

Print each substring reversed.

```
§θ±¹
```

Print the last character of the string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
a@-,2JWVRVUWTMa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/0UFXx8grPCwoLDQ8xDfxP1AkKTklNS0dAA)

<s>Seems like there's gotta be a shorter way, but I haven't found it yet.</s> Well, this is a bit shorter. Also, I think it's the longest run of capital-letter builtins I've ever used. :^P

#### Explanation

```
a@-,2JWVRVUWTMa
   ,2            Range(2): [0; 1]
  -              Negate: [0; -1]
a@               Use those values to index into the input string, giving a list
                 containing the first and last characters
     J           Join that list on the following expression:
              a  The input string
            TM   With first and last characters trimmed off
          UW     Unwoven into a list of two strings: the characters at even indices, and
                 the characters at odd indices
        RV       Reverse, putting the string of odd-indices characters first
      WV         Weave back together
```

Worked example with input `abcdefg`:

```
a                "abcdefg"
 @-,2            ["a" "g"]
            TMa  "bcdef"
          UW     ["bdf" "ce"]
        RV       ["ce" "bdf"]
      WV         "cbedf"
     J           "acbedfg"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>95</s> 76 bytes

```
func[s][prin take s t: take/last s
foreach[a b]s[prin any[b""]prin a]prin t]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BDoIwEETP9ivG/oB3r8R486DHpoelbCkBW9IWkK9HC@5l3kxespGb7cmN0sJeNzt5o5JWY@w8MvWMhHzd6TJQykjChshknCLUOh0i@VXVUuqjHJH19jexQImTfBkXwiALhTfXoVkLV44imcxxL/eq2oVMpsftYxz5ls9levDMEW3wntB2M2MNE6ZRCq0Efld@ZlgsQm9f)

Directly prin(t)s the characters instead of returning a string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 43 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("(?<=.)(.)(.)(?=.)","$2$1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9Na8MwDIbv/RWaacEZqWE79pNRtp22S49jB9V1UreObWwlLIz@9ixfdAUbWXpeSa/PWOH8fLw0uvAuEJzbXJSkjchKK0k7Kx6XE2kwRvhAbeF3AuDLg9ESIiG1oXL6CEXL@J6CtvnXN2DIY9JLAd7GOauBpkPYQAbrJs43UQTlDUr1YgxnfLtai4QPZ9s@Wcqmz9MnljTLftptBalIEdbjEgC2lyfnDEtvuSvUwR3r/8ruhAElqXBXet/t7loI5QVef@QJba4e/sGnqlSA3FmLkOtKQe1KKD3r@XVwlrnAKwy9scVgL7m560Ck0PrNBHpvat4JkuWI93UkVQhXkvDt/yjjbBYXMIszy9J@Vtq1j/rrpLvX5g8)

## Without much API, 60 bytes

```java
s->{for(int i=1;i<s.length-2;)s[i]^=s[++i]^(s[i]=s[i++-1]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBNa4NAEIbv@RVTIaA1LqTHGANFSk/tJUexsFlXs4nuyu5oK8HfblcjJodleeedj2fmQlsaXLLrIKpaaYSL1aRBUZK8kQyFkuQ1XLGSGgNfVEi4rQDq5lQKBgYp2q9VIoPKeu4RtZBFkgLVhfGmVIBYSdNUXO/ZmeokPUAO0WCCwy1X2hUSQUTbUOwNKbks8By8hZ5JRPoTmcT37e@Oygrh@8E29cJ@CKe@yzDkBg1E8zgA58jOSpXOZtGq4ieVdY9IbFEoQ66fQp9x/FSClF3h488yy4K/PIxv3nINhZKSQiFaDp1qoKmdye/vZONiLdUT2O6O5y109yvY22mLPHoE1YjzrjXtXC@c03JCGeM1ujZxCR47g7wiqkFS2@Uxd5212cHarKWzmZptQPLf@TRT6Vzbr8bXD/8)

Comment: As @Arnauld suggested to @ShieruAsakoto, you should be able to use `(?!^)` instead of `(?<=.)`.

Comment: Actually I think @histocrat's regex might be even shorter still.

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 16 bytes (SBCS)

The same program as below, with extra simplifying-ops added.

```
,(!½!2%¬-|$,,)(,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fR0Px0F5FI9VDa3RrVHR0NDV0/v8PTs7Iz8/5r5tZBAA)

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg) `-ir`, 18 bytes

You know, Jono's challenges are *definitely* easily doable in Keg.

```
,(!2/1!2%--|$,,)(,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fR0PRSN9Q0UhVV7dGRUdHU0Pn///gksTkbAXXiuSMxLz0VMX/uplFAA)

### Explanation

```
                   # Take an input from STDIN
,                  # Step 1. Output the first item.
 (!2/              # Repeat half of the length-of-stack times
     1!2%--        # subtract by 1 if that's odd
           |$,,    # Swap & output the two items
               )(, # Output the remaining items
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 73 bytes

Did some simple optimizations

```
Fn.new{|x|x[0]+(1..x.count-3).map{|y|x[y%2==0?y-1:y+1]}.join()+x[-2..-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FczRCsIgFIDhV5FBoIiHue4C6SLoBbocuxAxWmxncXKpzJ7d1u3/wR/JY/1YYvcVHTOsXhHQx62kkvp2kFwDJHDLikEdBcz2tZW8Uz50xrTnrPQpSz184bmMyIVMveoA1F7qLb@DnyHSGDz/78HZaeLN5WHJuuCpEaL@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), 7 keystrokes

```
C-f <f3> C-f C-t M-0 <f4> C-/
```

or 9 keystrokes without fn-keys

```
C-f C-x ( C-f C-t M-0 C-x ) C-/
```

[`C-f`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Moving-Point.html#index-C_002df-84) move forward one character

[`<f3>`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Keyboard-Macro.html#index-C_002dx-_0028-1146) start keyboard macro

`C-f`

[`C-t`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Transpose.html#index-C_002dt-1104) transpose the character under the cursor with the one before it

[`M-0`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html#index-C_002du-168) call the next command with numeric argument 0

[`<f4>`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Keyboard-Macro.html#index-F4-1140) run this macro and end definition, with argument 0, this macro is run indefinitely until a break occurs, i.e. when `C-f` goes past the last character

[`C-/`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Undo.html#index-C_002d_002f-1094) undo the last change, i.e. the last transpose, so that the end condition is fulfilled; this saves some keystrokes over vim because `u` undo after a recursive macro call undos all the runs of the macro instead of the last change

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```rust
|s:&mut[u8]|for i in 1..s.len()/2{s.swap(2*i-1,2*i)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDNbsIwDL7zFIZDlU6sE5xQJ04V2o0Lx2mq0pC0FTRhiVOogGfv3KqMdT4kdr4fO7beYas0VLzULITrBCioRumQlfrkMYbAoZ2D8fhbPYhdHCWCgnV7c3FQefz0q6@bMhZKKDUsoshFR0nWb8uri9yZn9jypXxdzOkM7@37yIbkkHmlpIU19M0j7tKsoWFYGKFJaylY@NQoFjwlf965c9JiKr@nzOE@jmniOFbWVKlHtWLBIIi8PlsaKHx8brC4T/qrX8FsJwpjjrM5zHaF6LKBNKCmkpnZNz1emUzuTTNmJAW3XKC0HSXhVKGgYsz5SJIepuSfP3JxgM1FFFznctq34XgQGxAXXuSankb8raxpebnRmkNe1hIa48GfOt2WEJmDNuQEdQnSNOAJIv29/QE)

An anonymous function, takes a mutable reference to a bytestring and mutates it in place.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
~bġ₂↔ᵐ↔ᵗ↔ʰcb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/vy7pyMJHTU2P2qY83DoBTE4Hkqc2JCf9/6/kl1qWWqSQnp@Xl6iQnlmWqlCZX6pQWqD0PwoA)

Doesn’t feel like a very efficent use of bytes…

#### Explanation

```
~b              Append an unknown character at the beginning of the input
  ġ₂            Split the input into groups of 2 characters
    ↔ᵐ          Reverse the order of the 2 characters for all groups
      ↔ᵗ        Reverse again only for the last one
        ↔ʰ      Reverse again only for the first one
          c     Concatenate into a string again
           b    Behead: remove the unknown character
```

The way `ġ₂` works is that it will construct groups of 2 consecutive characters from left to right, so we need to pair the first character with something random, to avoid it getting swapped with the second character. If the length of the string is even, then the last group will only have 1 character instead of 2 (since we added a random character), instead of having the predicate fail. The rest of the program (`↔` etc.) works as expected on a group of only one character.

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 67 bytes

```forth
: f 2dup 1 -3 d+ bounds do i 1+ c@ i c@ i 1+ c! i c! 2 +loop type ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxNCsIwFATgfU8xzTZEaN1ZEEE8QU6Q5qcRa19IU7Cnj0l184ZvHoyjmLyYXI2cL3DozRbQQZxhOEbaFrPCEJ7oOPSt5HEq2ooWPfhMFJD2YDGUjfDbOHxigLiClWEdMTQrg9SeaGYIjSygtx3J7JXld/cqKp1s/FsmpV94fLRXy2Tb0uYv)

Overwrites the input string

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f          \ start a new word definition
  2dup       \ make a copy of the string address and length
  1 -3 d+    \ add 1 to address and subtract 3 from length (skip first and last)
  bounds     \ get the starting and ending address of shortened string
  do         \ loop from addr+1 to addr+length-3
    i 1+ c@  \ get value at next char
    i c@     \ get value at current char
    i 1+ c!  \ write current char to next char
    i c!     \ write next char to current char
  2 +loop    \ end loop, move 2 chars ahead
  type       \ output string (using copied address & length)
;            \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 26 bytes

```perl
s/(?<=.)(.)(.)(?=.)/$2$1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX8PexlZPUwOC7IFMfRUjFUP9dKBcckZ@fg5XcX5ualJ@SiVXRmpmSiaEzIFSiTC64l9@QUlmfl7xf92CHAA)

Look-behind and look-ahead to the rescue.

Comment: ShieruAsakoto and histocrat seem to have shorter regexes.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Mono)](https://www.mono-project.com/), 212 bytes

```
using System;class b{static void Main(string[] z){var s=z[0];Action<string>w=Console.Write;w(s[0].ToString());int i;var l=s.Length;for(i=2;i<=l-2;i+=2)w(new string(new char[]{s[i],s[i-1]}));w(s.Substring(i-1));}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1Bb8IwDIX/indLxVptXEMmoYkbO3UShyqHkGXFWnGk2FCg6m/PMtjFtt57/p7n@hgp5nxipB7aK0s4aj84ZthPLE7QwzniF3w4JMWSSqyzcKums0vA5ta9WL32gpFWD/dtNO@ROA6h2SWUoEfFJdR8xvbuq6rSSAKo/wiD4WYbqJeD/o5JoVlqXJmhLmthltWoKIzwAN9Pf3CpsxN3aJ/LqF/tXHilomlP@/9cUYs2zznnVpz/gc2lvFEfnn4B)

Because why not?

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `Ṫ`, 6 bytes

```
ḣ2ẇR÷Ṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B8%A32%E1%BA%87R%C3%B7%E1%B9%98&inputs=&header=%CE%BB&footer=W%E2%88%91%3B%20%0A%E2%9F%A8%60School%60%7C%60Somebody%60%7C%60Character%60%7C%60CGCC%60%E2%9F%A9M)

Note that the test suite simulates the `Ṫ` flag.

-3 thanks to lyxal

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Ṫ&code=%E1%B8%A32%E1%BA%87R%C3%B7%E1%B9%98&inputs=School&header=&footer=) for 6

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B8%A32%E1%BA%87R%C3%B7%E1%B9%98&inputs=&header=%CE%BB&footer=W%E2%88%91%3B%20%0A%E2%9F%A8%60School%60%7C%60Somebody%60%7C%60Character%60%7C%60CGCC%60%E2%9F%A9M) for a test suite for the 6 byter

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 19 bytes

```
ispro[y,[pfo0]po]lo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zuKAoP7pSJ7ogLd8gtiA/Nif////gksTkbAXXiuSMxLz0VEUA)

```
ispro[y,[pfo0]po]lo
isp                  # Read input onto the stack, stash the last char and delete it
   ro                # Reverse the stack, print the first char
     [          ]    # Loops until the stack is empty
      y,             # Push the stack length and decrement by 1
        [p  0]p      # If-then, code runs if there's 2+ entries on the stack
          fo         # Flip the top two entries and print the top of stack
               o     # Print the top of the stack
                 lo  # Restore the "last char" from back cell and print
```

Comment: `ispro`...why is checking if the input is professional useful here? :P +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `j`, 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ṫsḣ²ṃ$h
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSVBQXMlRTElQjglQTMlQzIlQjIlRTElQjklODMlMjRoJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9U3RhY2slMjBFeGNoYW5nZSEmZmxhZ3M9ag==)

##### Explanation

```python
Ṫsḣ²ṃ$h  # Implicit input
Ṫs       # Extract the last character
  ḣ      # Remove the first character
   ²     # Break into pairs
    ṃ    # Reverse each inner pair
     $h  # Push the first character
         # of the input again
         # Join the stack into a string
         # Implicit output
```

Comment: Tsh? Isn't that the username of someone who golfs in javascript? What you doing golfing in javascript? I thought you golfed in thonnu 2. Goofy ahh nerd.